# xcode 4.5 - Propagation of a UIWebview from a Mainstoryboard to a language-specific Storyboard

Tags: ios, localization, uiwebview, xcode4.5, propagation

I'm working on a simple bilingual app. I put a UIWebview in the MainStoryboard --> it propagates to the English version (so that it runs well) but the French version is empty (the UIWebView doesn't propagate to the French version). Any idea of how to make the UIWebview propagate to the second storyboard ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very simple solution: http://techblog.41concepts.com/
Thanks to "mmc".